# Difference between $this->renderPartial() and $this->render() using $this->layout=false

Tags: php, yii

What is the difference between renderPartial and render with layout `false`?
I know `renderPartial` will not include layout.

`$this->renderPartial()` vs `$this->layout=false; $this->render();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not much. `render()` uses `renderPartial()` internally and wraps this in the `$layout` if set.

Look at the [source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/CController.php#L865):

```
public function render($view,$data=null,$return=false)
{
    if($this->beforeRender($view))
    {
        $output=$this->renderPartial($view,$data,true);
        if(($layoutFile=$this->getLayoutFile($this->layout))!==false)
            $output=$this->renderFile($layoutFile,array('content'=>$output),true);

        $this->afterRender($view,$output);

        $output=$this->processOutput($output);

        if($return)
            return $output;
        else
            echo $output;
    }
}
```

and

```
public function renderPartial($view,$data=null,$return=false,$processOutput=false)
{
    if(($viewFile=$this->getViewFile($view))!==false)
    {
        $output=$this->renderFile($viewFile,$data,true);
        if($processOutput)
            $output=$this->processOutput($output);
        if($return)
            return $output;
        else
            echo $output;
    }
    else
        throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{controller} cannot find the requested view "{view}".',
            array('{controller}'=>get_class($this), '{view}'=>$view)));
}
```

The three differences I can see are:

1. `render()` with `$layout = false` will run [`processOutput()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#processOutput-detail); `renderPartial()` will not unless you explicitly set it to do so.
2. `render()` calls [`beforeRender()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeRender-detail) and [`afterRender()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#afterRender-detail); `renderPartial()` does not.
3. in a scenario with multiple partial views, `renderPartial()` will never render any `$layout`; `render()` will if `$layout` is set in any of the partial views.